# CodeIgniter 3.0 with Foundation 5

Tags: codeigniter, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0 and Foundation 5. I also recently installed SASS/SCSS and Compass to make working with Foundation easier.

I'm wondering is it possible to use them together? The foundation CLI builds a new directory with all of the content, but I have an existing CI project I'd like to integrate it with.

Comment: Codeigniter is a PHP framework and Foundation 5 is related to CSS ! They are not related and YES you can

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'm asking how to use Foundation's SCSS with CodeIgniter, I already know that it compiles static CSS. However, I'm not sure how to use them together. 
Foundation:
    |- bower_components
    |- js
    |- scss
    |- stylesheets

and using compass watch when you update a *.scss file it updates/compiles a static CSS file. I'm a little confused on how to integrate that with the CI structure.

- whoops, looks like the line breaks were removed

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding an empty compass project into CodeIgniter, then copied the Foundation *scss* and *bower_components* directories into my source directory. Then adding `add_import_path src/bower_components/foundation/scss` to the config.rb to allow importing of the Foundation SCSS.

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "src/bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "src/css"
sass_dir = "src/sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "src/js"
```